# Anticompaction phase post nodetool repair in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After running repair on 3.11.2 version , I am getting below message in debug.log saying -
**mc-50-big-Data.db fully contained in range (-9223372036854775808,-9223372036854775808], mutating repairedAt instead of anticompacting**

*Why this SSTABLE is fully contained in range ( -9223372036854775808,-9223372036854775808 )
beside having muliple tokens / keys as shown is below output*

**Below key found in this SSTABLE**

```
sstabledump demo/msisdn-e59722f0d1e711ebb52c1524f01c1145/mc-50-big-Data.db| grep key

"key" : [ "1" ],
"key" : [ "2" ],
"key" : [ "22" ],
"key" : [ "833" ],
"key" : [ "3232" ],
"key" : [ "98" ],
"key" : [ "900" ],
"key" : [ "173" ],
```

**DIFFERENT TOKENS found in this SSTABLE**

```
account_id | system.token(account_id)
------------+--------------------------
1 | -4069959284402364209
2 | -3248873570005575792
22 | -1117083337304738213
833 | -1083053322882870066
3232 | -1016771166277942908
98 | -463622059452620815
900 | -300805731578844817
173 | 298622069266553728
```

I executed below command -

```
nodetool repair -full -seq demo msisdn
```

Comment: Why .. value inside the range is same ( -9223372036854775808,-9223372036854775808 )
Though repair completed successfully and anticompaction updated "Reapired at "  value of SSTABLE post completing the incremental repair ....

But I don't know why anti compaction not created two sstables with repaired and unrepaired .

Comment: Is anti-compaction not creates unrepaired sstables in C8 3.11.1  ?

Answer (score 0):

For C* older than
Example of what Anti - compaction perform with C* SSTABLES during repair .

- Cassandra older version > C* 2.2 was actually performing ANTICOMPACTION where one sstable splitted into two parts -
- repaired
- unRepaired

Below is the example .

Currently Repaired at of SSTABLES -

client:~/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.23/data/data/demo/msisdn-495d5c00d5ee11eb966cd7c730160a5d$ for i in `ls *Data.db` ; do echo $i ; ~/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.23/tools/bin/sstablemetadata $i | grep Repai ;done | grep -v commitlog

```
demo-msisdn-ka-1-Data.db
Repaired at: 0
demo-msisdn-ka-2-Data.db
Repaired at: 0
```

client:~/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.23/bin$ ./nodetool repair -st -5196837186409114737 -et -178801028445334456 -par -inc

```
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,270] Nothing to repair for keyspace 'system'
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,293] Starting repair command #6, repairing 4 ranges for keyspace system_traces (parallelism=PARALLEL, full=false)
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,395] Repair session 3bdd7000-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-5196837186409114737,-4923763406927773451] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,395] Repair session 3be05630-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-4923763406927773451,-2187651444700558944] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,396] Repair session 3be38a80-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-2187651444700558944,-574543093143405237] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,401] Repair session 3be62290-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-574543093143405237,-178801028445334456] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,421] Repair command #6 finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,437] Starting repair command #7, repairing 4 ranges for keyspace demo (parallelism=PARALLEL, full=false)
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,504] Repair session 3bf0f800-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-5196837186409114737,-4923763406927773451] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,504] Repair session 3bf1e260-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-4923763406927773451,-2187651444700558944] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,507] Repair session 3bf64f30-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-2187651444700558944,-574543093143405237] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,514] Repair session 3bf760a0-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d for range (-574543093143405237,-178801028445334456] finished
[2021-06-25 19:55:04,753] Repair command #7 finished
```

After repair -  Repaired at of SSTABLES -

client:~/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.23/data/data/demo/msisdn-495d5c00d5ee11eb966cd7c730160a5d$ for i in `ls *Data.db` ; do echo $i ; ~/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.23/tools/bin/sstablemetadata $i | grep Repai ;done | grep -v commitlog

```
demo-msisdn-ka-3-Data.db
Repaired at: 1624650904440
demo-msisdn-ka-4-Data.db
Repaired at: 0
demo-msisdn-ka-5-Data.db
Repaired at: 1624650904440
demo-msisdn-ka-6-Data.db
Repaired at: 0
```

---- LOG -----

```
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:7] 2021-06-25 19:52:19,665 Memtable.java:382 - Completed flushing /home/divyanshu_sharma/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.22/data/data/demo/msisdn-495d5c00d5ee11eb966cd7c730160a5d/demo-msisdn-tmp-ka-1-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1624646218285, position=185893)
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:52:19,713 Validator.java:257 - [repair #d9ad0620-d5ee-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:52:19,783 Validator.java:257 - [repair #d9c485c0-d5ee-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:52:19,845 Validator.java:257 - [repair #d9d21a50-d5ee-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:52:19,861 Validator.java:257 - [repair #d9d54ea0-d5ee-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,330 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3bdd7000-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/events
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,337 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3bdd7000-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/sessions
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,349 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3be05630-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/events
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,355 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3be05630-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/sessions
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,372 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3be38a80-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/events
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,374 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3be38a80-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/sessions
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,388 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3be62290-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/events
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,391 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3be62290-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for system_traces/sessions
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,413 CompactionManager.java:496 - Starting anticompaction for system_traces.events on 0/0 sstables
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,413 CompactionManager.java:561 - Completed anticompaction successfully
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:45] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,414 CompactionManager.java:496 - Starting anticompaction for system_traces.sessions on 0/0 sstables
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:45] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,414 CompactionManager.java:561 - Completed anticompaction successfully
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,453 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3bf0f800-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,472 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3bf1e260-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,485 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3bf64f30-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [AntiEntropyStage:1] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,496 Validator.java:257 - [repair #3bf760a0-d5ef-11eb-966c-d7c730160a5d] Sending completed merkle tree to /127.0.0.5 for demo/msisdn
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,516 CompactionManager.java:496 - Starting anticompaction for demo.msisdn on 1/1 sstables
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,516 CompactionManager.java:537 - SSTable SSTableReader(path='/home/divyanshu_sharma/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.22/data/data/demo/msisdn-495d5c00d5ee11eb966cd7c730160a5d/demo-msisdn-ka-1-Data.db') ((-7133164915313410844,6369609434230030255]) will be anticompacted on range (-5196837186409114737,-178801028445334456]
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,517 CompactionManager.java:1125 - Performing anticompaction on 1 sstables
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,517 CompactionManager.java:1137 - Anticompacting SSTableReader(path='/home/divyanshu_sharma/css/apache-cassandra-2.1.22/data/data/demo/msisdn-495d5c00d5ee11eb966cd7c730160a5d/demo-msisdn-ka-1-Data.db')
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,670 CompactionManager.java:1197 - Anticompaction completed successfully, anticompacted from 1 to 2 sstable(s).
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2021-06-25 19:55:04,678 CompactionManager.java:561 - Completed anticompaction successfully
```